# Single SCSS file for Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

The foundation framework for sites is great but there are lot of steps to start especially for a person who writes server side code.

We need the following:

1. Single SCSS file with all the code in it in the defined order with all the variables in it. I don't want to mention the include statements.
   This is required so that I can run simple sass command:

   ```
   sass input.scss output.css
   ```

   I know this can be done simply by combining the files in any text-editor but how to resolve the point mentioned below:
2. I read in the document that `auto-prefixers` are not in SCSS files so how these will be handled in the above case.

The one solution I have is to use the compiled CSS, but I still want to have flexibility to change the variables and compile with simple sass command.

Can you please provide solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Foundation CLI to generate a project from a template that addresses all of your concerns:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#command-line-tool

The ZURB template is the one you will want to use since it comes with autoprefixer:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html#zurb-template